# How to Update a file in my Resource folder in Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Can someone tell me how to access the Resources folder of my project. I mean , I want to update a file from that folder. I use this method:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@Properties.Resources.Clasament, richTextBox1.Text);
```

But doesn't work with `Properties.Resources.Clasament` as source . Other ideas?

Comment: The resources do not exist on disk when your application is built. The resources become part of the application binary.

Comment: @JohnSaunders So how can I update a file from that folder?

Comment: As John said, *there is no folder*, so there is no *file from that folder* to update.

Comment: In Visual Studio. When your application is deployed, there is no folder with files in it. Do you see a folder with files in it when you look on disk where your application is deployed? Or maybe you have never deployed the application?